# Angular select where id is something and add values

Tags: angularjs

I have a list with categories and then I need to dynamicly add subcategories to some of the categories.

say we have the following code:

```
var list = []
var cat = {
    "CategoryId": 1,
    "CategoryName": "Cat"
} // example of a category

list.push(cat);
```

And a douzen more are added, then there is a subcategory that looks like this:

```
var subCat = {
    "CategoryId": 1,
    "CategoryName": "Cat",
    "SubCategoryId": 1,
    "SubCategoryName": "some subCate"
} // example of a subcategory
```

And I need to find where the right Category is based on the `CategoryId` I tried doing it the following way:

```
// creating a category like this
list[CategoryId] = value;

// And for the subcat
list[CategoryId].SubCategories.push(value);
```

but this "fails" when the `CategoryId` is like 1,3,7,... (and In my case it is like this) because the length will be the highest id -1 instead of the real length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Object instead of Array:

```
list = {
    1: {
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "CategoryName": "Cat"
    },
    3: {
        "CategoryId": 3,
        "CategoryName": "Dog"
    }
};
```

Then you can access it through `list[id]`.